# Redux Store: What goes into data what goes into UI?

Tags: redux

It seems to be common practice to have separate stores for data and ui, respectively, e.g.

```
  store
  |
  +--- data
  |    |
  |    + foo.reducer.ts
  |    + ...
  |
  +--- ui
       |
       + bar.reducer.ts
       + ...
```

I'm wondering how to tell data from ui, there seems to be no clear distinction. For example, I might want to store the state of my sidebar (open, floating, pinned etc.), that clearly goes into `ui`. Then there are things such as app bar title which also appear to be a pure UI concern, although they have some relation to the data displayed in the view.

Next, I might have a list of objects (e.g. contacts) to choose from where I'd like to track which one is selected etc. While this still is to do with UI state these objects come from a data store and I might want to change the selected item(for instance, select a contact, pop up a dialog and edit the name of that contact).

Are there any hard and fast rules or guidelines that I can follow or am I left to my own devices?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't even bother making a distinction between the two. It'll be clear from your variable names.

`isSidebarOpen`

`contacts`

`selectedContact`

`isLoading`

Answer (score 1):

**Placing state in the store vs UI in Redux apps**

This is a subjective question and is difficult to answer. However there are some guidelines you can follow. Experience is the best teacher for this topic. Having said that best practice is to:

**Keep as much data as possible within your Redux store unless it is inconvenient to do so**

*Global data that is shared by components in your application belongs or mutates in complex ways belong in the store. The since the majority of your state in your app fits this criteria most of it should belong in the store.

By following this guideline and endeavouring to keep all applicaton state in your store you will stay true to the [single source of truth](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/ThreePrinciples.html) principle of Redux. This principle holds that

> The state of your whole application is stored in an object tree within
>   a single store.

Data that matters *globally* or can be mutated in a *complex* manner should go in *state*. If data is used by more than one part of your UI then it matters globally.

Data that only matters to one small part that doesn't mutate in a complicated way can go in the ui

*Ephemeral* Data that is only relevant to an *isolated* part of the UI such as whether some part of the UI is toggled can go in the UI.